# Retrieve only Visible sheets from workbook - OfficeScript

Tags: office-scripts

I am attempting to get a list of only the visible sheets in an Excel online workbook. I found the method .getNext({visibleOnly?: boolean}).

However, I don't know how/where to call it in the below code. I attempted to add it by reducing the sheets collection to a `visibleSheets only` collection.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let sheets = workbook.getWorksheets();
    let visibleSheets:ExcelScript.Worksheet[] = sheets.getNext({visibleOnly: true});

    visibleSheets.forEach(sheet =>{
        // Toggle auto filter on selectedSheet
        if (visibleSheets.getName() != "SUMMARY") {
        console.log(visibleSheets.getName())
        visibleSheets.getAutoFilter().apply(visibleSheets.getRange("A1"));
        // Apply custom filter on selectedSheet
        visibleSheets.getAutoFilter().apply(visibleSheets.getAutoFilter().getRange(), 0, {filterOn: ExcelScript.FilterOn.custom, criterion1: '<>'});
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of `getNext` in your code is not correct. `getVisibility` might be the better one to get the visible sheets.

---

**Option 1:**

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let sheets = workbook.getWorksheets();
    let sheetVis: ExcelScript.Worksheet [] = [];
    sheets.forEach(sheet => {
        if (sheet.getVisibility() === ExcelScript.SheetVisibility.visible) {
            // Your code to manipulate sheet, then you don't need sheetVis
            sheetVis.push(sheet);
        }
    });
    sheetVis.forEach(sht => {
        console.log(sht.getName());
        // Your code to manipulate sheet
    }
    );
}
```

---

**Option 2:**

Or you can get the list of visible sheet name.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let sheets = workbook.getWorksheets();
  let sheetVis = sheets
    .filter(t => t.getVisibility() === ExcelScript.SheetVisibility.visible)
    .map(t => t.getName());
  sheetVis.forEach(sht => {
    console.log(sht);
    // Your code to manipulate sheet
  }
  );
}
```

---

**Option 3:**

You can certainly achieve the same outcome using the approach of `getNext` if preferred.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let sheetVis = workbook.getFirstWorksheet();
  do {
    console.log(sheetVis.getName());
    sheetVis = sheetVis.getNext(true);
  } while (sheetVis)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful response and options. I appreciated the additional knowledge of using .push to add the sheet to the sheetvis array and the .filter/.map for filtering of the worksheet array. Based on the above if I added the IF evaluation for the sheet visibility and worksheet name it took the script nearly a minute to run. Converting the script to use the filter on the worksheet array caused it to run in about a second.